# Splitting bash command line argument

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

Is this the best way to split up a colon separated bash command line argument?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
hostlist=`echo $1| awk '{split($0,Ip,":")} END{for (var in Ip) print Ip[var];}'`
for host in $hostlist
 do
  ....
 done
```

Comment: Ask yourself if the code is readable or really cryptic. I think the code is hard to understand without extra comments, so there must be a better way to code it. That being said, I like the accepted answer from Shawn :o)

Comment: Yes I like simple, did think my solution was "over engineered" :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way would be to use [IFS](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03), the shell's built-in method to split strings into fields.

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=':'
set -f
for host in $hostlist; do
  set +f
  echo "$host"
done
set +f
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

`set -f` turns off filename generation (globbing): without it, wildcards `*?\[` would be expanded in each word.

Answer (score 5):

I think the simplest solution is just to use bash builtins:

```
#!/bin/bash
hostlist=${1//:/ }  # this will replace all : with a space

for host in $hostlist ; do
    echo ${host}
done
```

Another way (still simpler than your awk solution) is to use cut though this probably depends on GNU cut.

```
#!/bin/bash
hostlist=$(echo $1 | cut -d : --output-delimiter=" " -f 1-) 

for host in $hostlist ; do
    echo ${host}
done
```

Comment: This assumes there are no special characters (no whitespace or globbing characters) in the names. That's likely to be true in a “hostlist”, but not a general technique.